# Stochastic Process Corollary

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

Anyone mind explaining what does this mean in layman terms? Does it mean the probability of variance of W is infinity is equal to 1? Thanks!

Let (W (t))t∈[0,T ] be a Wiener process. Then P(Var[0,T ] W = ∞) = 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: 'Var' is not variance; it is total variation. Brownian paths are not  of finite variation.

Comment: Here is the proof provided by my prof. It seems that he meant variance here. Mind explaining a bit further please? Assume the contrary, that is, P(Var[0,1]W < ∞) > 0. From Theorem 2.3.4, it follows that there exists a sequence of partitions [0, 1] (tn) m(n), for n ∈ N, such that max i |tn (i+1) - ti| → 0 as n → ∞ and
summation of |W(tni+1) − W(ti)|^2 from i=1 to i=m(n)-1 → 1 (equation 1), almost surely. On the other hand, on the event {Var[0,1]W < ∞} we have summation of |W(tni+1)−W(tni)|^2 from i=1 to i=m(n)-1 ≤max|W(tni+1)−W(tni)|Var[0,1]W→0, which contradicts equation 1.

Comment: It is clearly the variation in your professor's proof.

Comment: ok thank you Kavi!

Comment: @Cathy For some guidance on how to write mathematics on this site, please consult [this MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thanks @JoseAvilez !

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, your confusion stems from the notation $\mathrm{Var}$.  In this context, it does not mean variance; instead, it refers to the "[total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_for_functions_of_one_real_variable)" of the function $t\mapsto W_t$.

In layman's terms, $\mathrm{Var}(W_t;[0,T])$ refers to the length of the curve $W_t$, but locally projected onto the $y$-axis; that is, we ignore changes in $x$-value in computing the length.  The statement then says that the "$y$-length" of $W_t$ is always (a.s.) infinite, even when we look at the smallest of finite time intervals.